# transforming data before displaying

Tags: reactjs

I have a time component that gets the data in seconds, but I would like to convert to minutes and round before displaying. I wrote the following code:

```
        var Time = React.createClass({
            minutes: function() {
                var mins = Math.round(this.props.data/60);
                return mins;
            },

            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div className="">
                        {this.minutes}
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
```

This didn't work (shows nothing, no error), I also tried the following:

```
        var Time = React.createClass({


            render: function(){
                var minutes = function() {
                    var mins = Math.round(this.props.data/60);
                    return mins;
                };

                return (
                    <div className="">
                        {minutes}
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
```

which also doesn't work (shows nothing, no error).

There seems to something key that I'm not understanding, but not sure what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: minutes should be called (it's a function) so `{this.minutes()}` in the first example or `{minutes()}` in the second.

Comment: Yes, what he/she ^ said.  On a different note, there is no reason to create a separate function for this task (functions should generally take an input argument and return a value) unless you declare it with a parameter (like `minutes: function (seconds)` ) and pass `this.props.data` as an argument.  You can just as easily put `var minutes = Math.round(this.props.data/60);` just before your `return` inside of render.

Comment: thanks, maybe create an answer so I can close the question? - Deryck, I agree I, just need to do a few more things in the function which I didn't mention in the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minutes` should be called (it's a function) so use `{this.minutes()}` in the first example or `{minutes()}` in the second.